# ColdFusion synchronous socket calls

Tags: sockets, events, asynchronous, coldfusion, gateway

I was researching about ColdFusion Event Gateway, I need to send synchronous method calls using sockets to a server..
is this possible in ColdFusion , because all the results I have found uses asynchronous method calls.. 
(just to be clear: I need the client to wait for the socket call response before continue the code, and not to call and continue asynchronously)

regards

Answer (score 0):

It depends upon how you call the event, and what you want to achieve.

Typically, what sort of waiting time are you looking at, and when you say "Client" are you referring to a browser, or the server-script that invoked the thread?

Comment: Client I mean a browser, this is the scenario again with little more details... the client connect to server using a socket, the client send a request for the server, the server do the math and return a string... the user exccute the command sent from server then repeat this process...

Comment: Are you wanting to do this without refreshing the browser window - like using ajax? It sounds like this is what you need.

With an ajax request, the javascript would fire off the request to a CFM script - this would then return to your browser, and ajax would catch the response.